# Add tomcat server credentials to project's pom and not settings.xml

Tags: maven, tomcat

I want to be able to build and deploy my java webapp on my local development installation of tomcat without adding the tomcat user's credentials to maven's settings.xml on every development computer. [Every article](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6553020/2577508) I've found requires modifying settings.xml.

I've attempted adding the  tag to my POM file and it doesn't seem to be allowed since I get errors about a "malformed POM" when I run "maven compile".

```
<project...>
    ...
    <servers>
        <server>
            <id>localhost</id>
            <username>admin</username>
            <password>password</password>
        </server>
    </servers>
    <dependencies>
    ...
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is given at the end of the article you quote

> The reason that credentials is set in the settings.xml is because your username and password should be secret in most cases, and there is no reason to deviate from the standard way of setting up server credentials that people will have to adapt to.

Your POM file would be normally committed into a source control system making it the worst place to keep senstive information. Passwords in the settings file can also be [encrypted](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-encryption.html).

Finally the POM file is designed to  hold information on how to build your code. The settings file is designed to setup environment speific settings for your build. Items like the location of your Maven repositories. Information on how the code is deployed would also fall under this category, you and I might share a codebase but we're unlikely to share the same tomcat server.

Comment: I understand that it isn't a good idea usually, but since all of the development machines are the same it would just be easier to be able to check it out and not have to worry about also modifying settings.xml. I just want to know if it's possible to override this behavior.

Comment: @John It is, just set the properties in your POM file.

Comment: I tried that already and I just get errors about a "malformed POM". Here's where I put it:
<project...>
 ...
  <servers>
       <server>
       <id>localhost</id>
       <username>admin</username>
       <password>password</password>
       </server>
    </servers>
    <dependencies>
    ...
</project>

Comment: @John Now I get you. No a servers section is used to provide credentials to items like repositories. Didn't realize they could be used for tomcat as well. One possible work-around is have a local settings file, called tomcat-settings.xml. Then run maven like "mvn -s tomcat-settings.xml" to pick up the file.

Answer (score 6):

You can try this:

`<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <url>${server-url}</url>
        <path>${deploy-path}</path>
        <username>${deploy-un}</username>
        <password>${deploy-pw}</password>
    </configuration>
</plugin>`

When you have many modules in your project, use `<profile>` in each module to deploy each module to different `URLs`. Ex:

In module A:

`<profile>
    <id>server1</id>
    <properties>
        <!-- Replace with URL and authentication if needed -->
        <server-url>http://localhost:8080/manager/text</server-url>
        <deploy-path>/moduleA</deploy-path>
        <deploy-un>tomcatscript</deploy-un>
        <deploy-pw>p@ssw0rd</deploy-pw>
    </properties>
</profile>`

In module B:

`<profile>
    <id>server1</id>
    <properties>
        <!-- Replace with URL and authentication if needed -->
        <server-url>http://localhost:8080/manager/text</server-url>
        <deploy-path>/moduleB</deploy-path>
        <deploy-un>tomcatscript</deploy-un>
        <deploy-pw>p@ssw0rd</deploy-pw>
    </properties>
</profile>`

DO NOT FORGET to add this into your `tomcat/conf/tomcat-users.xml`:

`<role rolename="manager-script"/>
<role rolename="manager-jmx"/>
<user username="tomcatscript" password="p@ssw0rd" roles="manager-script, manager-jmx"/>`

Then at terminal, use this: `mvn tomcat7:[re]deploy -Pserver1`

`moduleA` will be deployed to `http://localhost:8080/moduleA`,

`moduleB` will be deployed to `http://localhost:8080/moduleB`

Hope this helps!