# External JARs with Drools Workbench do not resolve on compilation

Tags: drools, drools-guvnor, kie-workbench

**Summary**

I have a drools workbench server that I want to push data model jars to from maven. I can push jars to it, but when I do, the artefacts do not resolve. If I try to upload the artefacts manually through the drools UI, I get other maven errors.

**Details**

I have a drools installation of drools and KIE 7.24 (and 23) (https://hub.docker.com/r/jboss/jbpm-server-full/) running in a local docker container. I want to push data models to workbench. My `pom.xml` of the project containing the facts looks like

```
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd"
         xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.release>11</maven.compiler.release>
    </properties>
    <groupId>decisions</groupId>
    <artifactId>fact</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>kjar</packaging>
    <name>Facts</name>
    <description>Facts</description>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.kie</groupId>
                <artifactId>kie-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>7.24.0.Final</version>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <distributionManagement>
        <repository>
            <id>workbench</id>
            <url>http://localhost:8080/business-central/maven2</url>
        </repository>
    </distributionManagement>
</project>
```

A `mvn deploy` on the host succeeds and builds. When I log into the drools container, I can verify that all the files are in `$DROOLS_HOME/bin/repositories/kia/global` and when I bring up the artifacts screen, they are [image] visible in the list.

When I try to add them as a project dependency, I get warnings from drools

```
07:49:16,790 WARN  [org.appformer.maven.integration.MavenRepository] (default task-50) Unable to resolve artifact: decisions:fact:1.0.0
07:49:16,791 ERROR [org.kie.scanner.MavenClassLoaderResolver] (default task-50) Dependency artifact not found for: decisions:fact:1.0.0
```

[image]
[image]

Everything in the drools workbench maven repositories looks perfectly ok, but no matter what I do, the artifact will not resolve.

If I try to upload it manually to the artifact store using the workbench admin repository tool, I get a huge stack trace from drools:

```
08:14:06,447 ERROR [io.undertow.request] (default task-56) UT005023: Exception handling request to /business-central/maven2: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.eclipse.aether.deployment.DeploymentException: Failed to retrieve remote metadata com.lendi.decisions:fact:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml: Could not transfer metadata com.lendi.decisions:fact:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml from/to workbench (http://localhost:8080/business-central/maven2): Unauthorized (401)
    at org.guvnor.m2repo.backend.server.repositories.DistributionManagementArtifactRepository.deploy(DistributionManagementArtifactRepository.java:145)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.AbstractBeanInstance.invoke(AbstractBeanInstance.java:38)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ProxyMethodHandler.invoke(ProxyMethodHandler.java:106)
    at org.guvnor.m2repo.backend.server.repositories.ArtifactRepository$475362908$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.deploy(Unknown Source)
    at org.guvnor.m2repo.backend.server.GuvnorM2Repository.lambda$deployArtifact$4(GuvnorM2Repository.java:300)
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:184)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:175)
```

Neither the drools manual or any references seem to have advice.

Comment: In settings.xml file, add <servers> tag  as mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6549504/maven-server-in-settings-xml .Define authentication details for business-central console.

Comment: The they are running on the same node in the same container, is the image not set up to authenticate to itself out of the box?

Comment: no, we have to provide details

Comment: Any solution was found ?